# A function that takes a number and a list and output a list with all the positions of that number in Erlang

Tags: erlang

How may I construct a function in Erlang that takes a list and a number X as inputs and it then returns the positions of all elements with that number X in a list?

I am a newbie in functional programming.

Answer (score 2):

Cool and fancy:

```
get_pos(L, E) ->
    [ P ||
      {X, P} <- lists:zip(L, lists:seq(1, length(L))),
      X =:= E ].
```

Old and boring:

```
get_pos(L, E) ->
    F = fun(X, {Acc, Pos}) ->
            A = if X =:= E -> [Pos|Acc]; true -> Acc end,
            {A, Pos+1}
        end,
    {R, _} = lists:foldl(F, {[], 1}, L),
    R.
```

Fast and efficient:

```
get_pos(L, E) -> get_pos(L, E, 1).

get_pos([], _, _) -> [];
get_pos([H|T], H, Pos) ->
    [Pos | get_pos(T, H, Pos+1)];
get_pos([_|T], E, Pos) ->
    get_pos(T, E, Pos+1).
```

Answer (score 1):

```
get_pos(L,E) ->
    {R,_} = lists:foldl(fun(X,{Acc,Pos}) when X == E -> {[Pos|Acc],Pos+1}; (_,{Acc,Pos}) -> {Acc,Pos+1} end, {[],1},L),
    R.
```